# What is the purpose of the "Links" field in the "Manage Display" UI?

Tags: 8, entities

In admin/structure/types/manage/my_content_type/display, you can hide/show the fields to display.
There is a *Links* field that you can also hide/show.

What is the purpose of this field? Nothing is changing in my output when I hide it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Links section is used normally in **Teaser** section/display to display links like add comment, read more, etc.

On **Node Full Display**, it is depending on configurations we do. Such as "**Add new comment**" link will only be visible when we disable "**Show reply form on the same page as comments**" check-box in comment field settings. You can also give a try to [Flag Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) or other contributed modules which adds links on Node display.

Please check screenshot below (Teaser Display):
[image]

The above screenshot is of default Teaser Display of node type *article*, which is being displayed on site home page. When we hide *Links* from teaser display, these links are no more visible in node teaser.

Following screenshot shows links working in Node Full Display:
Depending on **configuration we do in comment field (check screenshot below)**, comment link will be visible on Full Display.
[image]

Comment link visible, when **checkbox is disabled**.
[image]

Comment link is not visible, when **checkbox is enabled**.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks, you are completely right, but I think there is a bug, because it is working for the teaser but not for any other view mode (I just test it)

Comment: No its not a bug, it is depending on your site configuration, I've updated my ans with how it works in Node Full Display mode.

Comment: Many Thanks Yogesh, this is much more clear! But there is still a problem not related to the comment system: why the "read more" link only appears on the Teaser view mode?

Comment: Because Read more link take user to full node view from teaser, and from full node display it can't go to other view.

Comment: ok, but I have a view mode like a teaser. I called it "grid". I was expecting to see the "read more" link in it... I feel I am asking too much. Many thanks for your help!!!